# time(NULL); vs time(&something);

Tags: c

Real simple question. According to my man-page, these two will do the same:

```
time_t t;
time(&t);

printf("Time: %ld", t);
```

...

```
printf("Time: %ld", time(NULL));
```

So, what exactly is the benefit of passing a pointer to time? In case `time()` would fail due to no clock being available,  neither of the two variants will have any benefit in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The benefit would be that you do not have to copy the data into another structure after calling 'time'.

If you are e.g. preparing a buffer of data to send to another application/server you would have to copy the data, which is additional overhead. By passing a pointer into your data structure you could put it right in the correct place in one shot.

Of course if your only use for the data is to convert it to another format such as a text printf, then it is more efficient to call it with NULL and save the additional storage required by your first example.

Lastly since the time function uses a single location for storage of it's internal time structure the first method would be more thread-safe, although I cannot remember of the top of my head if 'time' is in fact thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Most examples I've seen pass `NULL`. I likewise see no benefit in passing a meaningful pointer, especially since `time_t` is pretty much always just an integral type.

Answer (score 0):

From the man-page:

time_t time(time_t *t);

"If t is non-NULL, the return value will also be stored in the memory pointed to by t."

I guess it's just legacy stuff.

Comment: The OP gets this. He's asking _why_ you would want to pass a non-NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to time_t value passed as a function argument -- 
IMO that is one reason why the syntax exists.

```
time_t *foo(time_t *dest)
{
     time(dest);
     /* do something with dest here */
     return dest;
}
```